# How to place image inside of several nested border line randomly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to place image inside nested borders line randomly.
Please help me! Thanks in advance

[image: Expected result]

How to place images in random position like above picture.

My code below:

- HTML: I don't care if the structure changes it just needs to work.
- CSS: Please note this is just 1 method I have tried I have been sitting here for about 2 hours messing with this and couldn't figure it out.

```css
.first {
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE7;
  width: 385px;
  height: 385px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.1rem;
}

.second {
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE7;
  width: 301px;
  height: 301px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.imgSecond {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.1rem;
}

.third {
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE7;
  height: 215px;
  width: 215px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 15%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.imgThird {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.1rem;
}

.forth {
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE7;
  height: 133px;
  width: 133px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.imgForth {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.1rem;
}

.fifth {
  width: 49px;
  height: 49px;
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3498&q=80" class="img" />

  <div class="second">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3498&q=80" class="imgSecond" />

    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3498&q=80" class="imgThird" />

      <div class="forth">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3498&q=80" class="imgForth" />
        <div class="fifth"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()` together with `Math.random()` to place the objects randomly. Obviously you need some knowledge of trigonometry to make it work.

Comment: may you explain it more detail if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problems in React typescript. I got code of [Mushroomator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17487348/mushroomator) and modified it.

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import styles from "./user-scan-modal.styles.module.css"

type RingStyles = {
  "--rotation"?: string
  "--size"?: string
} & React.CSSProperties

export const UserScanModal = memoComponent("UserScanModal", () => {
  const numRings = 5 // Change this to the number of rings you want to display
  const rings = []

  for (let i = 0; i < numRings; i++) {
    const randomDegree = Math.random() * 360
    const ringStyles: RingStyles = {
      "--rotation": `${randomDegree}deg`,
      "--size": `${385 - i * 82}px`,
    }
    rings.push(
      <div key={i} className={styles.ring} style={ringStyles}>
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>,
    )
  }
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  return <div className={styles["rings-container"]}>{rings}</div>
})
```

and css module here:

```
.rings-container {
  padding: 16px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.ring {
  --size: ;
  --rotation: ;
  position: relative;
  grid-area: 1/1;
  border: 2px solid #D9DFE7;
  border-radius: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  height: var(--size, auto);
}

.ring img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  height: 35px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(var(--rotation, 0deg))
    translateY(calc(var(--size, auto) * -0.5))
    rotate(calc(-1 * var(--rotation, 0deg)));
}
```

I hope this solved your problem!

Comment: thank you so much bro! I got your code and wrote it in javascript! It works!!

Answer (score 1):

To place them randomly on a circle you need to know the radius of the circle.
Then you can use `Math.random()` to randomly choose an angle obviously from 0° to 360° and the use the following formulas to place your images.

```
y = radius * sin(angle)
x = radius * cos(angle)
```

`x` and `y` and the `x` and `y` coordinates you need to place your images at which will be on the circle.

Here an example using JavaScript canvas showing how the maths works. You can execute the snippet multiple times to see that indeed random points are being created.
It is important to know that in a canvas the top-left corner has the coordinates `(0, 0)` which explains the calculation of the absolute values. Also you would need to know that `sin(90°) = 1`, `sin(270°) = -1`, `cos(0°) = 1` and `cos(180°) = -1` to make sense of the calculations.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
const radius = 45;

function drawCircle(context, centerX, centerY, radius, lineWidth = 1){
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  context.strokeStyle = '#000';
  context.stroke();
}

drawCircle(context, centerX, centerY, radius);

function randomAngle() {
  return Math.random() * 360;
}

function randomPointOnCircle(centerX, centerY, radius){
  const angle = randomAngle();
  const xRelativeCenter = radius * Math.sin(angle);
  const yRelativeCenter = radius * Math.cos(angle);
  const xAbsolute = centerX + xRelativeCenter;
  const yAbsolute = centerY - yRelativeCenter;
  return { x: xAbsolute, y: yAbsolute };
}

function drawRandomPointOnCircle(context, centerX, centerY, radius){
  const point = randomPointOnCircle(centerX, centerY, radius);
  console.log(`x = ${point.x}, y = ${point.y}`)
  drawCircle(context, point.x, point.y, 1, 2);
}

drawRandomPointOnCircle(context, centerX, centerY, radius);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

If you want to do it in CSS:

CSS has [`sin()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/sin) and [`cos()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cos) functions, however without some pre-processor there is no `random()` function (as far as I know) so you would probably have to use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to generate the random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We can define the images' positions similar to [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system): By rotating and offsetting from the center point.

The offset places the images onto the rings. The rotation beforehand will place them along the rings.

By randomizing the rotation, we randomly place the images along their rings.

```js
const rings = document.querySelectorAll(".ring");
rings.forEach(ring => {
  const randomDegree = Math.random() * 360;
  ring.style.setProperty("--rotation", `${randomDegree}deg`);
});
```

```css
#rings {
  padding: 16px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.ring {
  --size:;
  --rotation:;
  position: relative;
  grid-area: 1/1;
  border: 2px solid #d9dfe7;
  border-radius: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  height: var(--size, auto);
}

.ring img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  height: 35px;
  transform:
    translate(-50%, -50%) /*Center image on circle*/
    rotate(var(--rotation, 0deg)) /*Rotate around center relative to `--rotation`*/
    translateY(calc(var(--size, auto) * -0.5)) /*Offset onto circle along rotation*/
    rotate(calc(-1 * var(--rotation, 0deg))); /*Counter-rotate to have image upright*/
}
```

```html
<div id="rings">
  <div class="ring" style="--size:385px">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3">
  </div>
  <div class="ring" style="--size:301px">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3">
  </div>
  <div class="ring" style="--size:215px">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3">
  </div>
  <div class="ring" style="--size:133px">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3">
  </div>
  <div class="ring" style="--size:49px">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683265379492-8179a1fff9c3">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**:

- For an upright image, make sure to counter-rotate it after placement.
- For an image centered on its line, make sure to translate it accordingly (by half its size).

Comment: Appreciate for your job. I tried it. It helped me a little bit still working in my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SurushSurush You are still working on your issue? Perhaps provide more details, or consider opening a new question if your issue differs too vastly.